# Using Entity Framework with "dynamic" entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, anonymous-types, anonymous

For example I have 3 entities : product, tool, device. All of them have "id" and "Name" attributes. Now I try to write a method to fill entity's data into a combobox. But I don't now how to create a method that can pass any entity into it. Something like code below :

```
    private comboBox FillCombobox(List<EntityType>)
    {
        using (dowacodbEntities dowacodbEntities = new dowacodbEntities())
        {
            comboBox comboBox = new comboBox();
            List<EntityType> EntityList = dowacodbEntities.EntityType.ToList();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("id");
            dt.Columns.Add("Name");
            dt.Rows.Add(-1, "Choose one option");
            foreach (EntityType Entity in EntityList)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(Entity.id, Entity.Name);
            }
            comboBox.ValueMember = dt.Columns[0].ColumnName;
            comboBox.DisplayMember = dt.Columns[1].ColumnName;
            comboBox.DataSource = dt;
            return combobox;
        }
    }
```

Which **EntityType** can be *product*, *tool* or *device*.

Comment: Maybe have a super class with properties id and name, which product, tool and device extend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define interface:

```
public interface IBaseEntity
{
    int Id { get; }
    string Name { get; }
}
```

Implement that interface in your `Product`, `Tool` and `Device` classes (it can be implemented by your partial part if entities are autogenerated) and define your method as:

```
private ... FillCombobox<T>(...) where T : class, IBaseEntity
{
    using (var context = new Context())
    {
        var entities = context.CreateObjectSet<T>().ToList();
        ...
        foreach (IBaseEntity entity in entities)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(entity.Id, entity.Name);
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar base entity control for ASP.NET pages that we use and we follow the suggestion of Nathan Quirynen. There is a base entity control with in your case the properties ID and Name which are passed down to the subclasses. With this control we load the same drop down is then used for Orders, Equipments and all types of other entities.

```
public interface EntityLoader<T> where T : CommonEntity
{
  /*Load all the entities for the list*/
  List<T> LoadEntities();

  /*Load the single selected entity by its ID*/
  T LoadSingleEntity(String ID)
}

/*Common Entity to inherit*/
public class CommonEntity
{
  private String _entityID;
  private String _entityName;

  /*Unique ID of the entity*/
  public String ID 
  {
    get { return(_entityID);}
    set { _entityID = value;}
  }

  /*Entity Name*/
  public String Name
  {
    get { return(_entityName); }
    set { _entityName = value; }
  }
}

public EntityComboBox<T> where T : CommonEntity
{
    private comboBox FillCombobox(EntityLoader<T> dataLayer)
    {
            comboBox comboBox = new comboBox();
            List<EntityType> EntityList = dataLayer.LoadEntities();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("id");
            dt.Columns.Add("Name");
            dt.Rows.Add(-1, "Choose one option");
            foreach (EntityType Entity in EntityList)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(Entity.ID, Entity.Name);
            }
            comboBox.ValueMember = dt.Columns[0].ColumnName;
            comboBox.DisplayMember = dt.Columns[1].ColumnName;
            comboBox.DataSource = dt;
            return combobox;
    }
}
```